# Python: print but don't process control characters (print them literally)

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, control-characters, ipdb

(python 2.7)

I am used to debug stuff in my IDE and see if the service returns CR/LF/CRLF (actually important for my application).
However, now I am in this python project that is very tricky to debug. So, I am using ipdb and just printing my result.

However, the print method tries to be nice and processes the value in the result nicely for human reading (losing the information I am interested in).

Any tricks to see the actual control characters being used? 
My only idea so far is to replace `\n` with `-{LF}-`, `\r` with `-{CR}-` and that way I guess `print()` won't be able to prettify the string and I could see what is going on - but that looks like a fool trying to hack something that they don't need to hack, right? :)

To illustrate:

- What I am used to getting, in my nice java project: 
  **IDE > Debugger** 
  `result="new line following:\r\nHere."`
- What I see in ipdb when doing print():
  **Console** 
  `print(result)`
  `new line following:`
  `here`
- I am NOT interested in a "what type of line endings this message used" type of solution. The control characters style can change at any point in the message and in general I want a good high detail view, not an analysis.

Comment: Use `print(repr(result))`

Comment: And note it's backslash `\r\n`, not forward slash `/r/n`

Comment: Also: `print \`result\`` or `print 'result=%r' % result`.